# ansible vmware with Customization Specification Manager

Tags: ansible

I really enjoy using the vsphere_guest module for guest deployment and configuration automation. However, I also have existing guest policies via "Customization Specification Manager", which ansible doesn't seem to have official support for. Has anyone tried any third party approaches that allows existing GOCS to be orchestrated via ansible?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible 2.6 and vmware_guest is module in which we have parameter customization_spec.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/vmware_guest_module.html?highlight=vmware_guest

Comment: Hello, thanks for the clue, but please could you edit your post to summarize the documentation you are quoting?